# DBUnitのレコード単位の比較について

Tags: java, junit

いつもお世話になっております。

DBUnitの使い方で苦戦しておりますので知恵をお借りしたいと思います。

DBUnitで実テーブルとエクセルで指定したデータのの比較が出来ますが、
**実テーブルから指定レコードを取得して比較すること**は出来ますか？

★DBUnitで実テーブルとエクセルで指定したデータのの比較方法

```
    IDataSet databaseDataSet = connection.createDataSet();

    // DBから実際のデータの取得
    ITable actualTable = databaseDataSet.getTable("M_KEIYAKU");

    // 期待値データの取得
    IDataSet expectedDataSet = new XlsDataSet(
            new File("src/M_TEST.xlsx"));
    ITable expectedTable = expectedDataSet.getTable("M_KEIYAKU");


    // 期待値と実際のデータの比較
    Assertion.assertEquals(expectedTable, actualTable);
```

実施したい理由
　　複数のテストパターンを実施するとき、
　　それぞれのテスト終了でテストデータを削除してデータの整合性をとっていましたが
　　テスト実施後に、データの確認をしたいため。

Answer (score 1):

実装方法がわかりました。

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/jp/java/library/j-dbunit/
リスト2. DbUnitのクエリー機能